# Cannot install netaddr from MacBook

Tags: python, macos, pip

In Linux, I just simply run `pip install netaddr` and everything works just fine. However, in Mac OS X version 10.15.4, this doesn't seem to be as straight-forward:

```
[myuser:my-macbook-pro:~]$ sudo pip install netaddr                                                                                                                                 2:33PM/03.30
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
WARNING: The directory '/Users/myuser/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
WARNING: The directory '/Users/myuser/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting netaddr
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ba/97/ce14451a9fd7bdb5a397abf99b24a1a6bb7a1a440b019bebd2e9a0dbec74/netaddr-0.7.19-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.6MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.6MB 1.6MB/s
Installing collected packages: netaddr
Successfully installed netaddr-0.7.19
[myuser:my-macbook-pro:~]$ python                                                                                                                                                   2:33PM/03.30
Python 2.7.15 (default, Feb 12 2019, 11:00:12)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import netaddr
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named netaddr
>>>
```

Still doesn't seem to work even when running the exact same command with sudo permissions.

As of now, I continue having to fire up a VM to run this script that only requires this one module.

Comment: can you try with `python -m pip install netaddr`? it's possible that pip and python point to different installations

Comment: I get the following output from that: `/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: No module named pip`

Comment: Can you show the output of `which pip`?

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/pip` is the output from that.

Comment: Sounds great. See you there @jakub. Thanks!

Comment: For those interested you can discuss [in this dedicated chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210617/chatroom-for-https-stackoverflow-com-questions-60937203-cannot-install-netaddr)

Answer (score 0):

use virtualenv and install it from there
https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.